# Can not symlink app/Mage.php

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, modman

I want to deploy the Magento Core Files (Magento CE 1.7.0.2) through modman. However, when the file app/Mage.php is symlinked, the Magento Shop returns the install page.

When i restore the original file for `app/Mage.php`, everything works again.
First, I supposed the file permissions for the symlinked file are not correct:

File: `app/Mage.php`

- Symlinked: 777
- Original: 664

However, it is impossible to change the file permission of a symlink. 
In Magento Backend, the setting "dev/template/allow_symlink" is true.

The file `app/Mage.php` defines an incorrect magento root folder, when it is located for example at `magento_root/.modman/Magento_Core/app/Mage.php` and symlinked into `magento_root/app/Mage.php`. I could reproduce this with a magento vanilla installation.

Does anybody have an idea to overcome this issue?

Comment: Are you sure, that the original file and the symlink have the same owner?

Comment: Yes, they have the same owner.

Comment: I noticed that the symlink for app/Mage.php only works when the original file is in the same folder. For example this works fine: app/Mage.php points to app/Mage_original.php. However, my original file is located in a separate modman folder.

Comment: It can be a problem, if magentos \_\_DIR\_\_ get problems

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: I think you are right; at the top of the file Mage.php, the code line `define('BP', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));` unfortunately defines the magento root in the modman folder instead of the original magento root.

Comment: Please feel free to answer your own question, now you have figure it out :)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: Sorry, until now i have not found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important file `local.xml` must exist in the deployed modman-Folder, otherwise Magento returns the install page: `magento_root/.modman/Magento_Core/app/etc/local.xml`.

Magento does not seems to use the symlinked file `magento_root/app/etc/local.xml`.

Comment: Be careful, you might get problems in other places as well, where Magento uses `BP` or relative paths. Deploying the core itself with modman is not advisable. Relevant: https://twitter.com/fschmengler/status/601728826926858240

Comment: OK, thank you. I though this is "Best Practise", but you are right, then i get problems with custom template files.

Comment: Actually now i found what i want: The modman module "Magento_Core" is deployed through copying files and all other modman modules are deployed through symlink. The command `modman skip Magento_Core` prevents this module to be deployed when the command `modman deploy-all` is performed. Works fine!

Comment: Nice find, I did not know about `modman skip`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using apache make sure that is configured to follow symlinks as well.
`FollowSymLinks` is the what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I looked at my apache configuration (version 2.4.12), but i have already enabled this configuration:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/magento
    ServerName dev.mydomain.local                                                                            com
    ErrorLog logs/magento-error_log
    CustomLog logs/magento-access_log common
        <Directory /var/www/magento>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`